# How do I get the global point of a rotated object?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, rotation, movieclip

I'm trying to get the global point `(x,y)` of an object. This object is a child of a rotated parent, `MovieClip`. Without rotation of the parent, it's easy to find the global point of the child, `parent.localToGlobal`. However, when I'm rotating the parent, it seems that `localToGlobal` returns the incorrect `x,y`.

Comment: What do you mean by incorrect? Are you expecting the same x,y that you got without any rotation of the parent? Please elaborate more and post some code and some traced output to understand your question better.

Comment: It should be correct, but it's easy to get confused as to what the input point should be. To the find the "global point of the child" you would't typically use `parent.localToGlobal` as you say, you would use `child.localToGlobal`.

Comment: By "global point" do you mean the top left point i.e. (0,0) of the child, translated into global space?

Answer (score 0):

localToGlobal deals with position not transformation. You are simply using the wrong tool for the job. I'm guessing you don't want to deal with matrices but you gonna have to.

```
mydisplayobject.transform.pixelBounds;//global space occupied by object
mydisplayobject.transform.concatenatedMatrix//the matrix representing all combined transofrmations
```

Comment: It's really useful, while localToGlobal returns the same result. Thanks to you however I found my problem. When changing objects pivot points to center, it's works! Now I will have to find how to change my loaded sprites pivot point to center..

Comment: That's what people do when they can't face matrices and transformation. You dodge the problem and make your end user pay for it, so many Flash "would be coder" do that and that's the main reason why Flash is hated so much.

Comment: You said "That's what people do when they can't face matrices and transformation", so here I'm asking clearly: is there any way to handle it without changing object's pivot point to center?